# Java child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() null pointer

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file like this :

```
    <root>
    <item1>
    <object1>123<object1>
    <object2>321</object2>
    <fffxlink=""/>
    </item1>
    <item2>
    <object1>fsddf</object1>
    <object2>dsf</object2>
    <fff xlink=""/>
    </item2>
    <item3>
    <object1>7867</object1>
    <object2>87687</object2>
    </item3>
    <fff xlink=""/>
    </root>
```

I try to get all item ands object names with value of each object. The problem is that my code tries to get value of `<fff xlink=""/>` and I tried this `child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null` to ignore his value but I get always java null pointer exception

```
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/item/object/*");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        System.out.println("Nb objets : " + nodes.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println("item : " + el.getNodeName());
            NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();
            for (int k = 0; k < children.getLength(); k++) {
                Node child = children.item(k);
                if (child.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    System.out.println("object : " + child.getNodeName());
                    if (child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null)
                    {
                        if (child.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) System.out.println("Value :" + child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    }
                    else System.out.println("null");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the NullPointerException?

Comment: @LajosArpad  `if (child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null)`

Comment: Okay. What is null there? Is it child, child.getFirstChild() or is it happening somewhere inside those functions?

Comment: @LajosArpad child.getFirstChild() is null when he got from xml : <fff xlink="" />

Comment: Of course it is, because `<fff xlink="" />` is a node without children, so `getFirstChild()` returns null. How is that surprising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
<fffxlink=""/>
```

has no children, so it has no first child either, so

```
child.getFirstChild()
```

hence

```
child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

will throw a NPE.

Solution:

```
if ((child.getFirstChild() != null) && (child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue() != null))
```